# how to keep all bodies together

Tags: animation

hi I am new to blender and creating this animation where the phone hits the ground, but while falling down it breaks down into pieces how can I keep them together?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/15VLa.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object that has the dimension of your phone as a whole piece, make it invisble, parent all your pieces to this object, and give it the physics simulation.

Comment: hi, tried it but it glitches when the model touches the ground...

Comment: maybe share your file on https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: let me know if this will work: https://we.tl/t-ZsjnkyALv5

Comment: apply the scale of both the parent object and of the ground

Comment: yeah, it worked, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way is to use "*Object Constraint*" tools such as "*Child of*" or "*Copy Location/Rotation/scale*" on each component mesh

group each component as it should look when complete then parent using "child of" to an Empty (highly recommend) or primary piece of the phone (can get sloppy)

after parenting is done, you can animate as a solid mesh and also keyframe the individual pieces independently using "Influence"